# Google Apps Script - exeption: Invalid argument: 0

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

The function block below runs perfectly whenever I run it form Google Apps Script Editor, but generates an **Exception: Invalid argument: 0** when I run it from the appropriate site (docs.google.com).

I do not know what this exeption means, and also how to solve.

Could someone help me please?

```
function assignEventsColor() {    
  for (var i = 0; i < myevents.length; i++) {
    var thisevent = myevents[i];
    var title = thisevent.getTitle();
    if (/Comp/.test(title)) { thisevent.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.PALE_BLUE); }
    else if (/Matr/.test(title)) { thisevent.setColor(CalendarApp.EventColor.GREEN); } 
    else {}
      }
  }
```